# Python Cross-compiling for Mac on Windows

Tags: python, windows, macos, cross-compiling

I've created a program with Python 2.7 on my Windows 7 PC. I've compiled a version for Windows using cx_Freeze, but I can't find a way to cross-compile for a Mac user without using a Mac PC.

My research tells me that PyInstaller can't cross-compile, py2app doesn't work on Windows, and  cx_Freeze won't create a Mac application at all.

Is there any way for me to cross-compile for Mac from Windows?

Answer (score 3):

Even if you can build an application on Windows for OS X, you still wouldn't be able to test it, so there would be no way to ensure that you are delivering a functioning product.

You'd probably be better off find a computer with OS X, or a friend who has a Mac, and then writing a [cross-platform script](http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html#cross-platform) that would work with both py2exe and py2app.  Then, you'd just have to execute the script on both the PC and the Mac, and, BOOM, you'd have both programs.